# BeatifulSoup Extract String in div tag

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="interesting"><span>a</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>b</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;c</div><div>d</div>
```

I am trying to use `beautifulsoup` to extract the string `c`.

However, `soup.div.string` is `None`.  I could call `get_text()` to get `a b c` and then I parse the text again.  But I feel it defeats the purpose of using `beautifulsoup`.

Any suggestion?

=====================

Update:

I added `&nbsp;&nbsp;` to my example string above as I noticed that it actually causes `soup.div.find(text=True, recursive=False)` fails to return text in `div`.  So this question isn't a duplicate anymore.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('<div class="interesting"><span>a</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>b</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;c</div><div>d</div>', 'html.parser')
div = soup.find('div', class_='interesting')
print(div.find_all_next(text=True)[-1])
```

above code prints `d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you:

```
div = soup.find('div',class_ = "interesting")

print(div.find_all(text=True)[-1].strip()) #Prints the last text present within the div tag
```

Output:

```
c
```

Here is the full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<div class="interesting"><span>a</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>b</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;c</div><div>d</div>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')

div = soup.find('div',class_ = "interesting")

print(div.find_all(text=True)[-1].strip())
```

Comment: my example is oversimplified that the html string actually contains multiple parallel `div` tags.  And I locate the one I am interested in by `soup.fnd('div', class_='interesting')`.  However, if I chain it with `find_all_next(text=True)[-1]`, it jumps to the last `div` in the html string and digs out the text.

Comment: Oh...Then provide the actual html code.

Comment: The entire html is 61KB.  A bit too large.  I stripped out and updated my question.

Comment: Ok...Check out my latest edit.

Comment: hmm...still prints `d` instead of `c`.  I guess `div.find_all()` will include even other `div` tags in parallel to itself.

Comment: Oh...I have updated the full code in my answer. Check whether it prints ```c```.

Comment: Interesting.  Using `html5lib`'s parser, it works.  `html.parser` behaves differently.  Thanks!